# can't upload to s3 using boto3 and flask

Tags: flask, amazon-s3, boto3

this is basic thing and it seems obvious but am stuck in this one

am using boto3, I have this access key and secret key,

upload file route:

```
@app.route('/up')
def up():
 main = request.files['mainimg']
 bucket=<bucketname>
 if main:              
 upload_to_aws(main)
```

the upload_to_aws function (from github):

```
    import os
import boto3
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
    def upload_to_aws(file, acl="public-read"):
    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
    s3 = boto3.client(
        's3', 
        aws_access_key_id=os.environ.get('FASO_S3_ACCESS_KEY'),
        aws_secret_access_key=os.environ.get('FASO_S3_SECRET_KEY')
    )
    try:
        s3.upload_fileobj(
            file,
            "fasofashion",
            file.filename,
            ExtraArgs={
                "ACL": acl,
                "ContentType": file.content_type
            }
        )
        print('uploadeed')
    except Exception as e:
        # This is a catch all exception, edit this part to fit your needs.
        print("Something Happened: ", e)
        return e
```

I keep getting these errors:

- Access denied file must be a string
- File must be a string

Comment: What is `secure_filename`?

Comment: from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename